# Best way to handle OOV words when using pretrained embeddings in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am using word2vec pretrained embedding in PyTorch (following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710537/pytorch-gensim-how-to-load-pre-trained-word-embeddings)). However, it does not seem to handle unseen words. Is there any good way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

FastText builds character ngram vectors as part of model training. When it finds an OOV word, it sums the character ngram vectors in the word to produce a vector for the word. You can find more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828314/how-does-the-gensim-fasttext-pre-trained-model-get-vectors-for-out-of-vocabulary/50828479#50828479).